# Specifying scale for UIImage loaded from NSData

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

My app stores images as NSData objects. However, when these are loaded on an iPhone 4, they are displayed at double the size because the default scale factor is 1. I have 2 questions I would appreciate help with please:

1. Is there any way to set the scale of the UIImage without using `initWithCGImage:scale:orientation:`
2. If the answer to 1 is no, what is the most efficient way to load the NSData into a UIImage using the method above? At present it seems I will have to create a UIImage from the NSData and then create another UIImage using the method noted in 1 above.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. `UIImage` is immutable, so I guess there is no way to do so without hacking.
2. `UIImage` is just a wrapper of `CGImage` , so I think using `initWithCGImage:` as you describe won't have any noticeable performance impact. If you really worry about that, you can load it to `CGImageRef` first.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems I will be loading into memory 2 image objects, either 2 UIImage objects or a UIImage object and a CGImageRef. I have just tested this and it does have quite a performance impact, especially as these images are drawn in a UITableViewCell. I achieve better performance just drawing the image in a rect versus drawing at a point with a UIImage created using the method in my question.